# Predefined variable $s in PHP?

Tags: php

This is a very weird error. I am dealing with a script that uses variable `$s` as on object. This script has been running for a long time.

Randomly, on the page it suddenly said:

`Trying to get property of non-object...`

Confused, I put `var_dump($s)` on several places throughout the script, including the VERY TOP (before any includes or anything).

The output: `string(32) "8251ca989c1e9aec382f07f6e047e5f3"`

Even *more* confused, I put the `var_dump($s)` in another script to test it. Once again, it showed the same 32 character string.

What is happening here? Is this a hack of some kind?

EDIT:

I made a new script and this is LITERALLY the **entire** code:

```
<?php
var_dump($s);
?>
```

When I visit in a browser it says: `string(32) "8251ca989c1e9aec382f07f6e047e5f3"`

Comment: Where is this `$s` coming from?

Comment: `$s` is just a variable name I picked a long time ago (it's short for stats). This error just started today. The scary thing is it is not coming from anywhere. Let me edit the answer real quick.

Comment: Do you have `register_globals` enabled in php.ini? If so, is something passing a parameter named 's' to your script?

Comment: `register_globals` is on, although I have migrated *most* of my code away from needing it. Is there anyway to see what scripts still depend on it?

Comment: @hellohellosharp: Switch it off (possibly on a per-script basis using .htaccess) and see if anything breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

register_globals might be turned on, and the data might be coming from a cookie of the same name. You should [disable it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) if you can for [security reasons](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php).